# Java, Android fonts seems to be in quite low quality

Tags: java, android, fonts

I am creating this android game with java and have been starting to use fonts quite often but they seem to be in really low quality, especially when you make them big, of course. I am using androids standard font. Is there anyway to increase the fonts quality and if I do download / created a custom font would they be in the same low quality?

Comment: Are you certain that you are not zooming in on the rendered text instead of repainting the text in differing sizes? The font glyphs are typically vector based and scale property (unless you use a raster font which is a rare occurrence)

Comment: I am resizing it with:
    mPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing text yourself(rather than using TextView), make sure you set `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your AndroidManifest.xml. `targetSdkVersion` is crucial. Without setting `targetSdkVersion`, the text you draw may be wrongly scaled.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Comment: I have min as 8 and target as 15, was set by default when I created the project. Still makes it really low quality. Would there be anything else that I can do differently if I draw it with canvas.drawText(...)? In the paint or something, maybe.

Comment: Then you should show your code, do you draw to offscreen bitmap? if so, how do you create the bitmap?

Comment: I'll add my string handeling class in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I draw my strings:

```
public class ImprovedString 
{
    private String mText;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mPosX, mPosY, mOffsetX, mOffsetY;
    private Rect mBounds;

    public ImprovedString(String text,int textSize, int color, Align align, Typeface typeface, float posX, float posY)
    {
        mText = text;
        mPosX = posX;
        mPosY = posY;

        mBounds = new Rect();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        mPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        mPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(align);
        mPaint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length() - 1, mBounds);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, int width, int height)
    {
        canvas.drawText(mText, (mPosX + mOffsetX) * width, (mPosY + mOffsetY) * height + mBounds.height() / 2, mPaint);
    }

    public void setText(String t)
    {
        mText = t;
    }

    public void offSet(float x, float y)
    {
        mOffsetX = x;
        mOffsetY = y;
    }

    public Rect getBounds()
    {
        return mBounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can edit your question and put the code in your question, because this is not an answer. What I am concerned about is how you create the `Canvas` object.

Comment: In my gameloop thread I create the canvas inside the run function with Canvas c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(). And then I have this try catcher that draws the canvas with mGameView.draw(c) and in the finally block I call mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c). Can't figure out how to put code in the comment :(